# modulefile - module unload is not unsetting environment variables

Tags: linux, tcl, environment-modules, modulefile

I have a very simple modulefile:

```
#%Module1.0#####################################################################
puts stderr "Loading personal environment"
proc ModulesHelp { } {
    puts stderr "\tLoads personal environment"
    puts stderr ""
}
setenv MYTEMPVAR sometext
```

And here is my command line:

```
> env | grep MYTEMPVAR
> module load ~/wa/example_modulefile
Loading personal environment
> env | grep MYTEMPVAR
MYTEMPVAR=sometext
> module unload ~/wa/example_modulefile
> env | grep MYTEMPVAR
MYTEMPVAR=sometext
```

According to the [modulefile man page](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/modulefile.html) unload module command was supposed to turn all setenv's to unsetenv but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

More information:

```
> module --version
VERSION=3.2.6
DATE=2007-02-14

AUTOLOADPATH=undef
BASEPREFIX="/usr/share"
BEGINENV=99
CACHE_AVAIL=undef
DEF_COLLATE_BY_NUMBER=undef
DOT_EXT=""
EVAL_ALIAS=1
HAS_BOURNE_FUNCS=1
HAS_BOURNE_ALIAS=1
HAS_TCLXLIBS=undef
HAS_X11LIBS=1
LMSPLIT_SIZE=undef
MODULEPATH="/company/tech/tools/modules/sites/$SITE/Linux/:/company/tech/tools/modules/projects"
MODULES_INIT_DIR="/usr/share/Modules/init"
PREFIX="/usr/share/Modules"
TCL_VERSION="8.4"
TCL_PATCH_LEVEL="8.4.19"
TMP_DIR="/tmp"
USE_FREE=undef
VERSION_MAGIC=1
VERSIONPATH=undef
WANTS_VERSIONING=0
WITH_DEBUG_INFO=undef

Hello World

> env | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
```

For those unfamiliar with modulefiles (they do not seem to be that popular):

- modulefile is a simple bit of code that set or add entries to the PATH, MANPATH, or other environment variables
- modulefiles hide the notion of different types of shells
- modulefiles are written in the Tool Command Language, Tcl and are interpreted by the modulecmd program via the module user interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently working as intended:  http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2384340&group_id=15538&atid=115538

It seems you are expected to run `module unload example_modulefile` without giving it the full path to the module file.

Comment: The link is broken.  Not sure where the issue went (or what the title is).

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Modules (>= 4.0) correctly unload this full path modulefile.

With older versions, the `module unload` command does not correctly match the full path modulefile passed on the command line with the currently loaded module. As a result no module is unloaded.

Reproductible issue on older version (< 4.0):

```
$ module -V | grep ^VERSION=
VERSION=3.2.11
$ module load ~/modules/test
$ module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) /home/user/modules/test
$ module unload ~/modules/test
$ module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) /home/user/modules/test
```

As evil otto said, on older module version, short module name has to be used to unload this modulefile

```
$ module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) /home/user/modules/test
$ module unload test
$ module list
No Modulefiles Currently Loaded.
```

Expected behavior obtained on recent module version:

```
$ module -V
Modules Release 4.1.3 (2018-06-18)
$ module load ~/modules/test
$ module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
 1) /home/user/modules/test  
$ module unload ~/modules/test
$ module list
No Modulefiles Currently Loaded.
```